# Wordpress excerpt's Read More takes me to the same excerpt again

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is the "Read on" button that is shown under every excerpt, is redirecting me to the same excerpt, too, instead of taking me to the full post. I have a complete suspect of my code, it's probably 100% different to those codes I've seen around on tutorials for adding Excerpt, for example I don't require using the `< ?php the_content(); ?>` to display the post, or `< ?php the_excerpt(); ?>` for the excerpt. I'm no longer able to reach the developer who did the work so I'm just lost. To my best knowledge, you will need the Index.php to look at, so here you go.

Index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <article data-menu-block="news" class="homepage_news dark_bg">
            <div class="inner_wrapper row">
                <div class="left_column">
                    <h5>LATEST NEWS <span class="red">\</span></h5>
    <div class="news_list">
        <ul>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">

            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
                // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <?php else :
                // Show the default message to everyone else.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>


    </div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to post the solution so others with the same problem as you will know how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on `content.php` file in your theme folder.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

The above part load the external php file which is located in your theme folder. Most probably, there are more files exists like `content-page`, `content-tags` etc. depands of your developer.

Comment: Never mind guys I fixed it on my own. A moderator can happily close the question maybe :)